# Confused about automatic instances and moving sprites in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, dom

I created big Sprite called Space and big number of smaller sprites and keep them in array Cells.
Question 1.
When I trace Cell's names `(like Cells[i].name)` - it shows 'instance' and and even numbers 2,4,6,...
When I trace children of Space names `for (...Space.numChildren; i++){trace(Space.getChildAt(i).name)` it shows odd numbers 'instance1' 'instance3','instance5'

The question is why there are two sets of different sprites and with which one I need to work further - to change coordinates, colors and so on. How the two related to each other?

Question 2.
Both sets show x and y coordinates of all cells set to 0 although when I created them I set it to different values and I see them placed correctly on screen.
When I move (by mouse) one of the cells, I want to move the same way all of the group of cells w/o changing relative locations between them. I could do it with the second set of instances only, but strange way. I don't set new coordinates as one would expect - `c.x += dx; c.y +=dy`,
but `c.x =dx; c.y = dy;`
I need clarification on that.

Comment: did you create them in the visual editor or with AS3 code?

Comment: Hello and welcome to **StackOverflow**. As it happens, your question, as it is now, reveals exceedingly little useful information to be answered. Please **edit** your post to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You don't expect anyone to divinate what is wrong with the logic in your algorithm without actually showing the algorithm, do you?

Comment: First, do not rely on names, they can change in case you decide to add a something somewhere. Next, better add instances dynamically while organizing them into a grid of sorts (AS3 can use 2D arrays but not directly, more like a list of lists). Third, there is more to coordinates, you should check `Space`'s children coordinates, these should vary, if not, you have missed a DOM layer in this description. Normal X and Y are relative to parent's, use `localToGlobal()` to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all cared to answer.
I already figured it out. The problem was that I did not understand that in array I saved addresses of my as3 objects returned by new operator, but addresses of graphic objects has to be saved inside the class objects and I had to use them to access the images.